# MAAS fails to Commission nodes

Tags: virtualbox, maas

I'm evaluating MaaS/Juju. I followed instructions in this link http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.5/install.html to setup MaaS.

I'm running this in Oracle VirtualBox environment so Power options are not configured for the VMs.

PXE booting VM works fine. The node shuts down itself and registers with MaaS in Declared state.

Issues:

- When I Commission the VM (which is in the Declared state), first it gets IP-Config: no response after 60 secs - giving up errors. (See link below for a screenshot).
- Fails to mount the boot device and drops into initramfs prompt.

I've copied logs here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5gy9nnonbnccufo/AAD9o4awSOtyaCCmRe5q7rBva

Any help to get past this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: About the network issue, tell us about your configuration. What NIC(s) are you using?

Comment: MaaS and VMs are using eth0 and connected to VirtualBox NAT Network. NAT Network works more like your home router. Like I mentioned, the VM PXE boots and shuts off fine first time (which is when it registers with MaaS). Then the commission fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a bit weird, because the enlistment phase (I assume you powerer up that machine manually and let MAAS enlist the node), is very similar to the commissioning phase, at least with regards to DHCP and PXE.  So I'm surprised that commissioning fails if enlistment works.

I see someone posted a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/280811/maas-pxe-boot-fail-ip-config-no-response.

Comment: I expect the answer lies in the proper configuration of the VBox network. AFAIR it defaults to NAT which also runs DHCP services. This is likely to conflict (unpredictably!) with the DHCP server MAAS runs in order to manage the nodes. What you need is to set up bridged networking. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: The above referenced question is slightly different because the PXE boot never worked in that case due to a chipset issue. In my case, the PXE boot works just fine first time then something goes wrong during commissioning. As you see there are no apparent errors in the MaaS logs either.

Comment: Nick Veitch: When I create VM shell, I manually change the network to NAT Network. Otherwise the initial PXE boot (enlistment of node) would also fail.